# Fix header till next inside a scrolling container

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, containers

I'd like to do something like this

[Freeze Header until Irrelevant (HTML, CSS and JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385068/freeze-header-until-irrelevant-html-css-and-js)

but inside a container.

Is that possible?

Comment: not able to get what you mean by inside a container?

Comment: it's on a mobile website and I've go a header menu that's always on top. I wan to have the same effect as that [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BCtP8/3/) when I scroll in my content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. Maybe there's a better way to do it (like without jquery..) but well :)
[Getting a sticky header to "push up", like in Instagram's iPhone app using CSS and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279725/getting-a-sticky-header-to-push-up-like-in-instagrams-iphone-app-using-css-a#comment27441542_13293684)

Edit: but it's quite slow on mobile...